# Using jQuery, how to get sum of numbers from innerText

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the total sum of the results in Stocks, ETFs and Mutual Funds. No. of results are always shown within brackets.

```
<div class="tabWrapper contains">
   <a class="active" data-paramvalue="Equities" href="javascript:void(0);">Stocks (10)</a>
   <a data-paramvalue="ETFs" href="javascript:void(0);">ETFs (15)</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-paramvalue="Mutual Funds" class="last">Mutual Funds (5)</a>
</div>
```

For this html tag, I would like to get 30. Number 30 is derived by adding 10+15+5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
var re = /\(([0-9]+)\)/;

$('a').each(function() {
   var match = re.exec($(this).text());
   if(match && match.length > 1) {
      sum += parseInt(match[1], 10);
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 same anser and beat me.  You should add the `Radix` param to your `parseInt()` call, though.

Comment: Not only that, I had to edit the question to make sense out of it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Find the elements and `.each()` over them using RegExp to find the count and add it to a running total:

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/EbBv5/3/

(edit: added some error checking)

Comment: This is freaking insanely awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @slamsal: I have nothing against JAAulde, but my answer is also the correct one (and I answered first). Having jsFiddle is nice but you should choose your answers based on whether they are correct or not.

Comment: @Mrchief, When i ran your code, it was throwing me an error but when I used JAAulde code, it didnt throw me any error. But, now when I use your code, it doesnt throw me an error. Did you change some code after your initial post. I have nothing against both of you. I am actually thrilled about the response from you and JAAulde. I wish i could mark both of your answer. Since I got exactly what I wanted from JAAulde before you code worked, i would have to mark JAAulde. I appreciate your help on editing my question too. I am still getting used to with functionality.

Comment: I would not be offended for the accepted answer to change from me to Mrchief given the reason I gave him a +1

Comment: OK, JAAulde. I marked @Mrchief. Thanks all of you. This site gives me hope on collective intelligence.

Comment: @slamsal: I edited to include JAAlude's suggestion about the radix, and the check to see if there are any matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
var regex = /\(([0-9]+)\)/g;
jQuery("a").each(function(){

var match = regex.exec($(this).text());
sum = sum + match[1];



});
```

Comment: You need a parseInt in there or you're going to concat strings instead of adding numbers.